# How to join 3 tables without losing rows?

Tags: php, mysql, join, max, multiple-tables

I am trying to write a query that joins three tables, groups by an id column, and finds the max value of a column. However, if there are no values for a given row, then the entire table row is removed from the resultset.

I have a auction site, with different items. I am displaying `price` as `max(bid)` alongside the item on a page called active bids. My issue is that if an item has no bids, then the item is not appearing on the page until it has received its first bid.

I also have a column `min_price` so if no values are added in the bid column, I still have a minimal price displayed.

Is it possible to display the `max(bid)` as blank, but still get the item to appear? In short, I am asking how I can display a table row even if one of the columns has no value inserted (the column has `null` accepted, but still no result).

Here is my query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(max(bid.amount) , 0) AS amount, item.img, item.expirydate, item.iditem, item.description, item.min_price, seller.name  
FROM item,seller,bid 
WHERE seller.idseller=item.idseller 
AND idcategory=1
  and
bid.iditem=item.iditem
AND item.expirydate> curdate()
group by iditem;" 
    ;
```

PHP:

```
<?php $datasett = $tilkobling->query($sql);
<?php  while ($rad=mysqli_fetch_array($datasett)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <div class="artikkelbilde" id="tabell">
            <td>
                <img class="artikkelbilde" src="../images/<?php echo $rad ["img"];?>">
            </td>
            </td>
        </div>
        <td>
            <?php echo $rad["iditem"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $rad["description"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $rad["min_price"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?= $rad["name"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $rad["expirydate"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $rad["amount"]; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="Gibud.php"> Gi bud </a>
        </td>
<?php } ?>`
```

Here is the SQL for the three relevant tables, with the absolute minimal amounts of information, but the principle should be the same. I'm just struggling with getting the sql to retrieve items when the item has no bids:

```
CREATE TABLE `bid` (
   `idbid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `amount` INT NOT NULL,
   `idbuyer` INT NULL,
   `iditem` INT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`idbid`)
);

CREATE TABLE `item` (
   `iditem` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `min_price` INT NULL,
   `description` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
   `idseller` INT NULL,
   `idcategory` INT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`iditem`)
);

CREATE TABLE `seller` (
    `idseller` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idseller`)
);

ALTER TABLE `bid` 
    ADD INDEX `FK_item_idx` (`iditem` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `bid` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_item`
    FOREIGN KEY (`iditem`)
    REFERENCES `item` (`iditem`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE `item` 
    ADD INDEX `FK_seller_idx` (`idseller` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `item` 
    ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_seller`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idseller`)
    REFERENCES `seller` (`idseller`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

INSERT INTO `item` (`min_price`, `description`) VALUES ('200', 'coffeetable');
INSERT INTO `item` (`min_price`, `description`) VALUES ('400', 'lamp');
INSERT INTO `item` (`min_price`, `description`) VALUES ('600', 'painting');

INSERT INTO `bid` (`amount`, `iditem`) VALUES ('800', '1');
INSERT INTO `bid` (`amount`,`iditem`) VALUES ('1000','2');

INSERT INTO `seller` (`name`) VALUES ('Bob');
INSERT INTO `seller` (`name`) VALUES ('Rob');
INSERT INTO `seller` (`name`) VALUES ('Tob');

UPDATE `item` SET `idseller`='1' WHERE `iditem`='1';
UPDATE `item` SET `idseller`='1' WHERE `iditem`='2';
UPDATE `item` SET `idseller`='2' WHERE `iditem`='3';
```

Comment: @mickmackusa I added the SQL for creating a basic version of the schema only with the relevant tables on SQL Fiddle. Keep in mind i have never used it before, so i may have misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: Apologies, added the seller now aswell. I am sorry for all the back and fourth, i am just trying to get into this, and it is a bit overwhelming to begin with. Thankfully so many kind people are willing to help.

Comment: p.s. You should tidy up your php because you have some broken dom/html going on.  (get those div tags out of your table markup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your posted sample data for the three tables, you can use a couple of `LEFT JOIN`s to ensure that all of the `iditem` values are preserved.  Consequently, when joined tables don't sync up with tables to their left, you'll see some `NULL` values.

```
SELECT `item`.`iditem`, 
       COALESCE(MAX(`bid`.`amount`), 0) AS `amount`,
       `item`.`description`,
       `item`.`min_price`,
       `seller`.`name`  
FROM `item`
LEFT JOIN `seller` ON `seller`.`idseller` = `item`.`idseller`
LEFT JOIN `bid` ON `bid`.`iditem` = `item`.`iditem`
WHERE `item`.`idcategory` IS NULL  /* because you didn't give this bit of data, nor the expiry */
GROUP BY `item`.`iditem`;
```

Here's my [sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/494fd5/10) to prove the query's success on your sample data.

When performing JOINs you should include an `ON` clause that determines which columns are acting as the glue.

The `WHERE` clause is now at your disposal to configure to your project requirements.  Be sure to clarify which table certain columns come from so that you don't get errors based on ambiguity.

Backtick-wrapping tablenames and columns may be overkill (and some devs don't like the bloat) but I find this to be sensible in eliminating the possibility of accidentally using a RESERVED mysql word.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever use COALESCE in mysql??

I think you should have something like this in your query

```
SELECT COALESCE(max(bid) , 0) AS max_bid FROM tables1
```

COALESCE return the first non-null expression in a list

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i absolutely think you are right, i updated my query to the above, but my issue is that when a single column has no values, i still want the other columns for that specific itemID to display on my site. So i essentially want the table row to be viewing regardless of the max(bid) has any values.

Comment: could you write your query here??if above query could't help you then you should define default value(i mean 0) for that column .it's the easy way and i am sure it fixed your problem

Comment: If your problem get solved then accept my answer else let me know what the problem is after above query

Comment: Hello, i am sorry for vague comment. I meant i added the query for my site in my post. I still have the same issue as earlier. Where my site is hiding the entire item row if there has not been added any bids, rather than displaying a blank column if no bid values are added.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the correct JOINS in your query, and not rely on the FROM [ table1, table2 ] statement, since that only use a regular JOIN.

You might want something like this:

```
SELECT 
   COALESCE(max(bid.amount) , 0) AS amount, 
   item.img, 
   item.expirydate, 
   item.iditem, 
   item.description, 
   item.min_price, 
   seller.name  
FROM item 
LEFT JOIN seller on seller.idseller = item.idseller
INNER JOIN bid on bid.iditem = item.iditem

WHERE 
   item.expirydate > curdate()
   # add your idcategory here, prefixed with the tablename

GROUP BY item.iditem;
```

PS: I did not add your `idcategory=1` because I'm not sure in which table it occurs.

An INNER JOIN will try to JOIN a record, if that record is not found, it will add `null` values for every INNER JOINED field you want to SELECT, the COALESCE will choose either the first argument, or the second if the first is `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i changed my query to the one you suggested, however, it still does not retrieve the items where none bids has been added. Only items that has been bid on appears, but i want to display all items even if no bids for that item exists.